# Jenkins error ImportError: No module named boto3

Tags: jenkins, boto3

everyone.
There is Jenkins running on my ubunut host.
Trying to execute the creation of the "aws ECR" in Jenkins file.
but,`Jenkins error ImportError: No module named boto3`error

my jenkins file

```
node {
 stage('Clone repository') {
     checkout scm
 }

 stage('Build image') {
     app = docker.build("xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/xxx")
 }
 
 stage('Create ECR') {
     steps {
     '''
     sh 'pip3 install boto3 --upgrade'
     sh 'python3 ecr.py'
     '''
     }
 }

 stage('Push image') {
     sh 'rm  ~/.dockercfg || true'
     sh 'rm ~/.docker/config.json || true'
     
     docker.withRegistry('https://xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com', 'ecr:ap-northeast-2:xxx-aws-ecr') {
         app.push("xxx")
         app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
         app.push("latest")
 }
```

}
}

Thanks you!!

Comment: So the error comes from `ecr.py`?

Comment: An error occurs when you run Pipeline                                                                 
                   ->>  Jenkins error ImportError: No module named boto3

Comment: Does the pip3 command error? what's the full output?

Comment: + python ecr.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ecr.py", line 1, in <module>

    import boto3

ImportError: No module named boto3

script returned exit code 1